# Changing bootstrap theme and colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

Twitter Bootstrap comes with its source code in the form of Less files. So if I want to change the default size of the top navbar for instance, then I'd have to (as far as I understand) do this in the `theme.less`.

But what if I'd like to change some default colors as well. These are defined in the `variables.less` file. Should I alter that file? Or should I (in the form of good practice) override them (if that's even possible) in the `theme.less` file as well?

I'd like to know the good approach for this, because I'd like to create my own Bootstrap theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we do at our team (and best practice) is to include a custom variables files at the bottom of all bootstap's imports. This way, all variable you declared will overwrite bootstrap's default and you will not being overwriting bootstrap, what will give you the possibility of update without conflicts.